# Power BI: filter on forecast version

Tags: filter, powerbi, dax

I am in a bit of a puzzle here and hope you guys can help:
I have the following table showing our forecast version:

[image: Forecast version table]

Our forecast process works in the following way:
On the first day, each month, we get a new "SOP Version" and "LAG 1". After some days the "latest" LAG-version changes from  "LAG 1"  to "LAG 0" for the rest of the month.

Example in table: Latest "SOP Version"=SOP5. From "day 1" to fx. "day 4" the table will be loaded with "LAG 1" only. On "day 5" the table will be enriched with "LAG 0".

Now, what I want to make is a dynamic (global) filter, which always filters the latest "SOP" and "LAG"-version on the Power BI report I have.

I have managed to make a summarized table in Power BI filtering the "lowest" LAG value for each SOP-version:

```
SOP&LAG (Latest Vers) = SUMMARIZE('Forecast';'Forecast'[SOP Version];"LAG (lowest value)";MINX('Forecast';'Forecast'[LAG]))
```

But I can't figure out to isolate the the latest SOP Version (SOP5) with its latest LAG-version (LAG0).
I am not even sure this is the right approach?
All ideas will be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks.
Br,
Jakob

Comment: Why is this SOP5 i.o. SOP05 like the other SOP's???

Answer (score 0):

I think you can filter your table with TOPN() like this:

```
TOPN(1;SOPLAG;SOPLAG[SOP Version];DESC;[SOP Version];ASC)
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, that helped me the rest of the way. :-)